# How to drop local state in git

Tags: git

How would you drop local state in git ?

Eg. you are 199 commit ahead of `origin/MyBranch` on you local `MyBranch` unfortunalty all that you have done is nonsense ...

What I want to achieve is something similar to :

```
cd ..
rm my-git-dir
git clone https://github.com/Me/my-git-dir.git
cd my-git-dir
git checkout MyBranch
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've posted?  You can just create a function in your `.bash_profile` if it's that important.

Comment: Well I knew by instinct that git offered a command for this (I couldn't be the first to face that) so I wanted to learn to do it the *right way*. @peter answer is just what I was looking for. I can even spare the first line (checkout) since I was already on the good branch ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout MyBranch
git reset --hard origin/MyBranch
```

Comment: For conpletenes you may want to tell what - eventually - happens to the 199 superfluous commits.